# python patsy intercept term in cubic splines

Tags: python, spline, patsy

I'm trying to understand cubic spline generation in patsy library of python. As far as I can see from the output of

```
import numpy as np
from patsy import dmatrix

x = np.linspace(0., 1., 100)
y1 = dmatrix("bs(x, df=6, degree=3, include_intercept=True)", {"x": x})
print(y1)
y2 = dmatrix("bs(x, df=6, degree=3, include_intercept=False)", {"x": x})
print(y2)
```

the `y1` (with intercept) and `y2` (without intercept) are the same. Is there something I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered on the patsy issue tracker:

https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/108#issuecomment-309234408

tl;dr: they are different, but eyeballing big matrices full of floating point numbers is hard :-)